# How to make GET request to Yelp api using volley?

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, android-volley, yelp

I am using Volley to make get request to Yelp Api and keep getting "BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search" error. I made GET request on Postman using the same parameters and headers and it worked just fine. Yelp has released their new API v3 recently,so  I did not find any useful similar problem on stackoverflow.

```
StringRequest stringrequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            "https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search",
            new Response.Listener<String>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    }catch(JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                    progressDialog.hide();
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            //headers.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            headers.put("Authorization",[Bearer myToken]);
            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("latitude",latitude);
            params.put("longitude",longitude);
            params.put("radius","15");
            return params;
        }
```

};
        RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringrequest);